# Are there any benefits to duplicate connection pools in Weblogic?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a cluster of 4 Weblogic instances on 2 servers. My JDBC connection pool is targeting the cluster.

Would there be any benefit if I duplicate the connection pool to the same database, and use the multi data source connection?

Is it possible that 1 connection pool could become unusable, but the other be ok, even though they are identical to each other? would this increase availability?

I tried to Google this, but could not find any answers.

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your database layer.

1. **One single database**
   If you have one single database, there will be no benefit at having a Multi Data Source with two (or more) datasources pointing to the same database. If the database falls, there's no magic.
2. **Database Cluster**
   If you have two databases in active-active mode, then the Multi Data Source feature will give you benefits. For this mode, choose Load Balancing algorithm: since both servers are active and with updated data then you may increase performance. If you have active-passive mode then you may consider Failover algorithm.

For Oracle RAC, ignore Multi Data Source and focus on the [GridLink Data Source](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/INTRO/jdbc.htm#FIFEBICJ).

Make sure to read [Configuring JDBC Multi Data Sources for 12.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/JDBCA/jdbc_multidatasources.htm).